# XSLT aggregating XML tag values and storing new tag

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to xslt and trying to process below XML using XSLT :

```
<xml>
<characters>
<char a="a1" b="b1" y="y1" z="z1"  weight="100">F</char>
<char a="a2" b="b2" y="y2" z="z2"  weight="80">r</char>
<char a="a3" b="b3" y="y3" z="z3"  weight="80">o</char>
<char a="a4" b="b4" y="y4" z="z4"  weight="100">m</char>
</characters>
</xml>
```

to produce output XML :

```
<word>
<value>From</value>
<coordinates>a1 b1 y4 z4</coordinates>
<avgWeight>90</avgWeight>
</word>
```

where coordinates form the first and last characters coordinates and avgWeight aggregate the values of weight tag.

Since XSLT variables are immutable, I'm unable perform below operation. Help me in finding solution.

Comment: **What have you tried?**

Comment: I have rolled back your question to its original form. Please post a new question with your new problem. Make sure to indicate if you're using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since XSLT variables are immutable, I'm unable perform below operation.

I don't see what variables, immutable or not, have to do with it. This is just straightforward XSLT:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/xml">
    <xsl:for-each select="characters">
        <word>
            <value>
                <xsl:for-each select="char">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </value>
            <coordinates>
                <xsl:value-of select="char[1]/@a"/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="char[1]/@b"/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="char[last()]/@y"/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="char[last()]/@z"/>
            </coordinates>
            <avgWeight>
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(characters/char/@weight) div count(characters/char) "/>
            </avgWeight>
        </word>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Please check the updated query, For which  variables should be used. Can you please guide me

Comment: If you know that variables should be used, then you know more than I do. In any case, this is a significantly different problem. Post a new question.